# How to make datatable when click row

Tags: react-native

*When I want to click "Text" click event, Open datatable with 3 columns header. I mean when you click text row, details of row will appear in datatable*

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container} key={counter = counter + 1}>   
    <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {marginLeft:'5%'}]}> {alb.Tescil_No} </Text>                                                                                   
    <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {marginLeft:'6%'}]}> {alb.GumrukAdi} </Text>
    <Text style={[styles.textStyle, { marginLeft:'5%'}]}> {alb.ACIKLAMA} </Text>                                                
  </View>   
)
```

Comment: I think you need to re-write your question and clarify what it is you are trying to do, because as it stands it is very unclear.

Comment: hi @andrew, I edited question

Comment: Unfortunately your edit doesn't make it any clearer as no-one knows what the datatable is and how it relates to your text row.

Comment: Like c# datatable bro. or anytable. Just I want to  get some details  about row. information will be taken from  json. Then table will be filled